# Fetching Api issue in Select Box

Tags: reactjs

As im fetching the free api in select box options in material ui select box the menu items are not displayed, and the page only is not visible

```
import axios from "axios";
function Apif() {
  const [users, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((response) => {
      setUser(response.data);

      //    console.log(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <option key={user.id}>
            {user.name} | {user.email}| {user.phone}
          </option>
        ))}
        ;
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Apif;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add import react, useEffect and useState

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Working link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-bird-fvnms?file=/src/App.js)!